# Ошибка при создании PhantomJSDriver Selenium Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, selenium, phantomjs

Хочу сделать скриншот сайта. Использую `phantomjs`. Запускаю в отдельном потоке.
Но тут `WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();` возникает ошибка:

```
Unable to open file '/var/lib/tomcat8/phantomjsdriver.log'

  phantomjs://platform/fs.js:79 in open
  phantomjs://platform/logger.js:95 in addLogFile
  phantomjs://platform/config.js:76 in apply
  phantomjs://platform/config.js:98 in init
{"chats":0}
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'vps429624', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-83-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:625)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:95)
    at com.online.utils.Screenshot.run(Screenshot.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(DefaultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    ... 10 more
```

КОД.

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", PATH);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Screenshot(URL, FILE));

public class Screenshot extends Thread {

    private String URL;
    private File OUTPUT;

    public Screenshot(String url, File output) {
        this.URL = url;
        this.OUTPUT = output;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            driver.manage().window().setSize(Online.SCREEN_SIZE);
            driver.get(this.URL);
            //FileUtils.copyFile(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE), new File(IMAGE + SEPARATOR + IMAGE_NAME));
            FileUtils.copyFile(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE), this.OUTPUT);
            driver.quit();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено.

Была ошибка из-за того что `phantomjs` не мог записать в лог файл.